# pandas Getting just the mean (float) value of one column when another column matches value in python

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe

Lets say I have a simple table

```
manufacturer    marbles     shape     blah
A               169         square    yada
B               140         round     yada
C               420         round     yada
C               380         square    random
D               400         round     dontmatter
D               222         square    lkj
D                89         round     asdf
```

this is imported into a pandas data frame with index being manufacturer.  In this example I want the mean value of marbles where the shape is round.  What I have now returns a series:

```
return df.loc[df['shape'] == 'round', ["marbles"]].mean()
```

I dont want a series returned, I want just the float mean of marbles.

Comment: `df[df['shape']=='round'].mean()`

Comment: `df[df['shape']=='round']['marbles'].mean()` for the specific column.

Comment: @Kaymal I was under the impression to not have back to back brackets in pandas

Comment: @wwii, that returns none.  I need the mean of the values in the marbles column that correspond to the shapes that are round.  I think you are trying to get the mean of the actual shapes which doesn't work or really make sense.

Comment: `df.loc[df['shape'] == 'round', ["marbles"]].mean().values`

Comment: @wwii heh, thats close.  It returns a ndarray with length 1.  And sure, I could add [0] at the end of that but there has to be a better way than df.loc[df['shape'] == 'round', ["marbles"]].mean().values[0]

Comment: Did you search, surely you are not the first to want that.

Comment: I searched a good amount and found nothing...just similar questions on returning data frames and averages of multiple columns etc.  Nothing like this unfortunately.  Your solution DOES work, I'm just not sure its the ideal solution

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are passing in a list of column names, which returns a series since each numeric column in that list will have a mean.

```
df.loc[df['shape'] == 'round', "marbles"].mean()
```

Passing in a scalar column label returns a float.

Answer (score 2):

You can have the mean of all your shapes

`df.groupby('shape', as_index=False).agg({'marbles': 'mean'})`

```
shape    marbles
round    262.25
square   257.00
```